# Why I can't login to MySQL server with after created user by query?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have an application that creates database, tables and users on MySQL server. There is no problem about creating database, tables and users but when I tried to login with created user, I'm getting this error:

```
Aborted connection 40 to db: 'db_16001' user: 'xxx@outlook.com' host: 'localhost' (init_connect command failed)
```

**My queries;**

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `db_16001` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;

USE `db_16001`;
CREATE TABLE `aboneler` (
`abone_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`ad_soyad` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`telefon` varchar(13) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`e_posta` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`sifre` varchar(8) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`yonetici` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
 PRIMARY KEY(`abone_id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE USER 'xxx@outlook.com'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT EXECUTE, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT, GRANT OPTION ON `db_16001`.* TO 'xxx@outlook.com'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

When I login as root user to MySQL server with Workbench, I can see the database, tables and users with their privileges but I can't login with that user.

Comment: Is this user also granted for creation of table?

Comment: I'm creating database and tables as root user.

Comment: Aha, sorry. Well, I wouldn't create username with symbol @. Maybe to use (at) instead? Try with backticks before @. Query seem fine

Comment: Unfortunately @BorisP :( I changed user name using workbench and retried but didn't work.

Comment: Hm.,sorry then for username. I had the same problem once, I granted all permissions to a user, but couldn't login. I did flush privileges. It worked when I restarted mysql.

Comment: I granted all permissions and I restarted the mysql but didn't work.